# The prefix of discord bot seems not working

Tags: c#, discord, bots

I started learning c# language and deciced to create discord bot and everything seemed good and everything (bot started, logged into) but my prefix to him doesn't work. I just wanted to check on 1 command if it would answer but nothing was really happening. Maybe i messed up a little? I'm using c#. Dont mind the names of anything. Here's code :

```
public class CommandHandler
{
    public static IServiceProvider _provider;
    public static DiscordSocketClient _discord;
    public static CommandService _commands;
    public static IConfigurationRoot _config;

    public CommandHandler(DiscordSocketClient discord, CommandService commands, IConfigurationRoot config, IServiceProvider provider)
    {
        _provider = provider;
        _discord = discord;
        _commands = commands;
        _config = config;
         
        _discord.Ready += OnReady;
        _discord.MessageReceived += OnMessageRecieved;
    }

    private async Task OnMessageRecieved(SocketMessage arg)
    {
        var msg = arg as SocketUserMessage;

        if(msg.Author.IsBot) return;
        var context = new SocketCommandContext(_discord, msg);

        int pos = 0;
        if(msg.HasStringPrefix(_config["prefix:"], ref pos) || msg.HasMentionPrefix(_discord.CurrentUser, ref pos))
        {
            var result = await _commands.ExecuteAsync(context, pos, _provider);

            if (result.IsSuccess)
            {
                var reason = result.Error;

                await context.Channel.SendMessageAsync($"Wystąpił błąd:\n {reason}");
                Console.WriteLine(reason);
            }
        }
    }

    private Task OnReady()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Connected as {_discord.CurrentUser.Username}#{_discord.CurrentUser.Discriminator}");
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

And the most basic command, which even didnt work cause something is wrong here

```
class General : ModuleBase
{
    [Command("Ping")]
    public async Task Ping()
    {
        await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync("Pong!");
    }
}
```

And the config.yml file is correct I guess

```
prefix: '-'
```

Comment: You should debug your code to see where things are going wrong. Does your `OnMessageRecieved` method get called for example? If it does, does `_commands.ExecuteAsync()` get called? If so, does it return successfully or is there an error?

Comment: It returns succesfully, i don't see any errors but some code isn't working properly. I changed if (!result.IsSuccess) from if (result.IsSuccess), and now it answers but even when i call command Ping doesnt return pong just has error

Comment: Nvm i'm kinda stupid just started programming and made some stupid mistakes, no "!" near result.IsSucces and i haven't written public class when i created new class so bot couldnt get info, but thanks for help! Have a nice evening!